# Why can tuple-unpacking provide a correct result when using two lines doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, greedy

I was working on the "maximum product subarray" problem and I ran into an issue with my code

The way I solved this problem was

```py
def maxProduct(nums):
   minProd = maxProd = maximum = nums[0]
   for i in range(1, len(nums)):
      currentNum = nums[i]
      maxProd = max(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
      minProd = min(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
      maximum = max(maximum, maxProd)
   return maximum

print(maxProduct([-4, -3, -2]))
```

My solution would give me 72 but the code that would give the correct solution is:

```py
def maxProduct(nums):
    minProd = maxProd = maximum = nums[0]
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        currentNum = nums[i]
        maxProd, minProd = max(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum * minProd), min(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
        maximum = max(maximum, maxProd)
    return maximum


print(maxProduct([-4, -3, -2]))
```

My solution and the correct solution seem to do the same thing. Why would

```
maxProd, minProd = max(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum * minProd), min(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
```

vs

```
maxProd = max(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
minProd = min(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
```

make such a big difference?

Comment: Pay attention to when `maxProd` changes!  Which `maxProd` do you want to use when calculating `minProd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the value of `maxProd` when you calculate the second value?

In the first example,

```
max(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum * minProd), min(currentNum, currentNum*maxProd, currentNum*minProd)
```

is calculated and then unpacked and assigned.

In the second example, the new `maxProd` value is calculated and assigned, and then used in the second calculation.